# Subselect on array_agg in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions, postgresql-9.2

Is there a way to use a value from an aggregate function in a having clause in Postgresql 9.2+?

For example, I would like to get each `monkey_id` with a 2nd highest `number` > 123, as well as the second highest number. In the example below, I'd like to get (monkey_id 1, number 222).

```
monkey_id | number
------------------
1         | 222
1         | 333
2         | 0
2         | 444

SELECT 
  monkey_id, 
  (array_agg(number ORDER BY number desc))[2] as second 
FROM monkey_numbers 
GROUP BY monkey_id
HAVING second > 123
```

I get `column "second" does not exist`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to place that in the having clause

```
SELECT 
  monkey_id
FROM monkey_numbers 
GROUP BY monkey_id
HAVING array_agg(number ORDER BY number desc)[2] > 123
```

The explanation is that the `having` will be executed before the `select` so `second` still doesn't exist at that time.