# Postgres: filtering results using ARRAY_AGG and HAVING (instead of WHERE)

Tags: sql, postgresql

So my database contains a listing of items:

```
items:  item.id | item.title
```

And I have a second table that associates a number of tags with the items:

```
tags:  tag.id | item.id
```

An item may have several tags (e.g. 5, 20, and 25) associated with it, and thus would have a row for each of those tag-values in the tags table.

I want to be able to determine if a particular tag is associated with an item, without losing all other tag data.  For example,

```
SELECT items.id, items.title
FROM items
INNER JOIN tags ON (tag.tag_id=items.id)
WHERE tag.id =27
```

doesn't work because it eliminates the rows containing the other tag values (if tag.id is 27, it cannot be any other value on a particular row).

To solve that, I want to use ARRAY_AGG to roll up the individual tag numbers into an array, against which I can (should) easily test values for membership.

```
SELECT items.id, items.title
FROM items
INNER JOIN tags ON (tag.tag_id=items.id)
GROUP BY items.id
HAVING ANY(ARRAY_AGG(tags.tag_id)=27)
```

(I saw [this post about how you can't SELECT an AS-named column with ARRAY_AGG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16821764/subselect-on-array-agg-in-postgresql) )

But the above code produces a syntax error on the ANY portion of the HAVING clause.

Thoughts?

Comment: I was using the tags table to filter the results from the items table.  For example, items may have one or more of 5 tags (1=Good, 2=Bad, 3=Red, 4=Green, 5=Yellow) and I want to select items that are both Good and Yellow.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Turns out that Postgres's [ANY keyword](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-comparisons.html#AEN18479) is sided and can't be used symmetrically.

Thus the working code is:

```
SELECT items.id, items.title, ARRAY_AGG(tags.tag_id)
FROM items
INNER JOIN tags ON (tag.tag_id=items.id)
GROUP BY items.id
HAVING 27 = ANY(ARRAY_AGG(tags.tag_id))
```