# ActiveRecord find instances where no associations with attribute exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Trying to come up with a scope that will find all `Parents` whose `Children` have NO `Pets` named "Bob"

```
Parent.includes(children: :pets).where.not("pets.name = ?", "Bob")
```

Will find all parents with a pet named something other than "Bob", but I want to want to find all parents where NONE of their pets are named "Bob"

For example:

```
parent | child | pet.name
  1        1     "Mr. Cat"
  1        1     "Barker"   
  1        2     "Snuggles"
  2        3     "Bob"
  2        4     "Carl"
  3        5     "Bob"
```

I would expect the query to return ONLY parent 1, since parent 1 has 0 pets named Bob. However, the scope instead returns parents 1 and 2. Since parent 2 has a pet named "Carl", and "Carl" != "Bob".

Comment: I don't think you can do this in pure active record.  Try looking at aggregate functions https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-aggregate.html.  You can also get away with 2 active record statements.  `parent_of_bob_ids = Pet.where(name: 'Bob').pluck(:id); Parent.where.not(id: parent_of_bob_ids)`

Comment: I'm more than happy to use aggregate functions. I'm just struggling to build the scope. I'd prefer to not have to do multiple queries, but will if that's the only way.

Comment: not really an sql expert so not sure about the performance implications of those aggregate functions.  personally, i'd go with the 2 sqls.  Just remember to add an index to the name column on Pet model

Comment: try `Parent.includes(children: :pets).references(children: :pets).where("'Bob' != ANY(ARRAY_AGG(pets.name))")`

Comment: I haven't used those functions before. You can't use aggregate functions in a `where` clause, but I'm getting syntax errors when trying to use them in `SELECT`, `GROUP`, or `HAVING`.

Comment: try to pattern the sql like the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19943327/postgres-filtering-results-using-array-agg-and-having-instead-of-where

Answer (score 0):

You can use **not ilike**

```
Parent.includes(children: :pets).where.not("pets.name not ilike ?", "%Bob%")
```

edited code

```
Parent.includes(children: :pets).where("pets.name not ilike ?", "%Bob%")
```

Comment: Doesn't work. :( Again, this finds the any parent that has at least one child not named Bob. But I'm looking for parents that may have a number of Children, but none of them are named Bob.

Comment: Sorry my mistake.

Comment: Just remove not from the where clause

Comment: No- it doesn't work because it's the wrong scope. This scope is essentially the same as my original scope, which doesn't work because it finds the wrong objects.